# What is the term when individual parts of product design and development done well but released product has terrible UX?

Tags: terminology, product-management, product

It's more prevalent in large corporations, also called something like "teams not talking to each other".

Like when product has great UI but bad integration with hardware that results
in terrible UX.

For example, in modern Android TVs the UI may look very nice and sleek but overall operation is sluggish, because UI was designed and tested on faster hardware and pushed to less capable hardware. Both teams did their work right but integrated result is bad.

Comment: I always knew it as *UI design gap* or *UX gap*, no idea if there' is an official name, but if you search Google for those terms you' find a lot of results, so it seems to be an accepted convention. Anyway, Im also looking for answers, good question.

Comment: Researching about your question, I found the concept of **_The Valley of Disappointment_**, something I don't know about, so it would be interesting to find an answer applied to UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out in the question, there are a number of reasons why this happens and there are any number of formal or informal ways to describe it, so perhaps I can suggest some here and see if other people in the community would like to add to it.

- Teams/individuals not talking to each other = working in silos
- Deficiencies in the handover process resulting in gaps = throwing
  something over the fence
- Differences in the maturity/skill level of teams = delivery team
  balance

I would say that what you are essentially describing also covers the fact that the first part of the double diamond process is intended to find the 'right problem to solve' which is about coming up with the root cause of a problem or identify an opportunity, and the second part of the double diamond is about 'solving the problem right', which is about designing and building to the specifications.

That means there could also be incorrect assumptions made in the initial research process or perhaps changes or differences in the requirements during the delivery process (e.g. UI was designed and tested on faster hardware and pushed to less capable hardware).